# woocommerce retriving category name as div class?

Tags: wordpress, class, woocommerce

ok I am trying to retrive the category name of a woocommerce product displayed in a wordpress loop and use it as the class for a li also inside the loop i've tried this:

```
 <div id="isocontent" class="products">
                <ul><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


                        <li class="<?php echo $product->get_categories(); ?> box">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> " class="amount price" data-original="<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); ?><?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>" data-price="<?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>" title="Original price: <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>"><?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); ?><?php echo $product->get_price(); ?></span></a>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>?add-to-cart=<?php echo $post->ID ?>" class="pbutton">Add to Cart</a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

this being the part i'm trying to retrive the class with:

```
<li class="<?php echo $product->get_categories(); ?> box">
```

but it just outputs this:

```
<li class="&lt;a href=" http:="" localhost.no="" fanny="" kategori="" interior-sv="" "="" rel="tag">
```

which does retrieve the category but also screws with the markup  breaking the loop. 
I've also tried this:

`<li <?php post_class('box'); ?>`

but because woocommerce uses taxonmys it retrives the tags but not the product category. 
any help is much appriciated
Kind regards 
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite as easy as making a single call - `get_categories()` is designed to show an HTML representation of the product categories. The product categories are actually a custom taxonomy, so you have to use [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) to get at it.

```
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ){
    $category_id = $term->term_id;
    $category_name = $term->name;
    $category_slug = $term->slug;
    break; 
}
```

Comment: can i adapt this to return the sub caterogries on the /taxonomy-product_cat.php page?

Comment: It should give you the sub category by default if that's what the product is assigned to. If you want to traverse, check out: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56784/get-main-parent-categories-for-a-product